# Securing Cookies on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, azure, cookies, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set the cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId" to use https to make it secure.  This is required for a security scan, even though the cookie itself does not seem to be carrying a lot of data.  I added this to my web.config (under system.web):

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

When I run this locally, I can see the that the cookie is set as secure (looking in browsers developer tools, under Cookies, the column "Secure" is checked).  But, when I publish to Azure and I check the same cookies, I can see that "Secure" is not checked.  Is this something that needs to be configured on the Azure host or in my application?

thanks

Comment: "even though the cookie itself does not seem to be carrying a lot of data" - sure, it only carries the session ID. And if someone was to intercept that session ID because it was delivered over HTTP, then they can potentially steal the session and thus obtain access to data they shouldn't be allowed to have. It's important to understand the security issues you're fixing.

Comment: Thanks.  yes, that is why I am trying to fix it.  Any thoughts on how?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies and then seeing if the server issues you a new cookie that  has the Secure set correctly?

Comment: I found some other config file settings I could set that did the trick.  I added them to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this to the web.config file, under `<system.webServer><outboundRules><rewrite>` node:

```
        <clear />
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=lax" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=lax" negate="true" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
```

in addition to what I already had and that seemed to have worked